# migrate git to perforce import

Tags: git, perforce, migrate, git-p4

I have a problem to migrate from git to perforce:

My Situation: I want to move from one perforce server to my own perforce server. I can only access to the depot my Perforce User is allowed.

So i tried git-p4 to export my perforce depot with all history. This worked, I now have the data in a git repository.

But now I'm trying to get this git repository ( with all history) on my new perforce server, but I don't know how to do this. I tried to set the P4 config (P4PORT,P4USER) to

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try Git Fusion.  You can basically use Perforce as an upstream Git repository and push in your history.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using debian squeeze linux and have problems to install the P4Python. I have python 2.7.3 and the latest p4api and p4python. But when i execute "python setup.py --build --apidir /api/dir" then i get a lot of error messages and the gcc exits with status 1. Do I need something else to install the p4python?

Comment: Ok, I installed first python 2.7.3RC from debian testing, this doesn't work. Then I downloaded the Python-2.7.3.tgz from python page and installed it. Then I was able to build the p4python.

Comment: You probably just needed to install the python devel packages.